# erlang vs jvm (scala) recursion performance

Tags: performance, scala, recursion, erlang, jvm

As an exercise of learning scala and functional programming, I implemented the following non tail-recursive def that calculates the [pascal's number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) at any location. The program itself serves as the definition of pascal's triangle. It looks pictorially as follows

```
      1
    1  1
   1  2  1
  1 3   3 1
 1 4  6  4 1
1 5 10 10 5 1
...

def pascal(c: Int, r: Int): Int =
  if (c == 0 || c == r) 1 else pascal(c - 1, r - 1) + pascal(c, r - 1)
```

However when trying to run for `pascal(25,50)` on Mac OS X 10.6.8 (2.53 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo) it still hasn't finished running after **20 min**.

Just to compare with erlang, I installed R15B02 and wrote equivalent program as follows:

```
-module(pascal).
-export([calc_pascal/2]).

calc_pascal(0,_) -> 1;
calc_pascal(C,R) when C==R -> 1;
calc_pascal(C,R) when C<R  -> calc_pascal(C-1,R-1) + calc_pascal(C-1,R).
```

`pascal:calc_pascal(25,50)` finishes in **~4sec**.

Why might be the reason for such a huge performance difference? Is jvm not as advanced as erlang runtime for recursive programs?

Comment: scala code was run in eclipse by compiling and running from junit, not from REPL

Comment: `calc_pascal(C-1,R)` should be `calc_pascal(C,R-1)`

Comment: Whoever downvoted this should comment on why... From the FAQs on downvoting: `egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post`, which is clearly not the case...

Comment: You'll also run into problems with Int overflow. In Scala (and Java) Ints and Longs overflow silently, rather than letting you know with an exception. Try something like: `def pascal(c: Int, r: Int): BigInt = Seq.iterate(Seq(BigInt(1)), r)(a => (BigInt(0) +: a, a :+ BigInt(0)).zipped.map(_ + _)).last(c)` (there are more efficient ways to get an individual number, but this simply calculates the whole triangle and returns the relevant cell).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I make the same mistake in the Scala program that you made in the Erlang version, it runs very fast. Might this be the reason?

Comment: oops! Erlang program corrected and it seems to be running forever as well. Thanks for pointing out. I guess this elegant looking recursive implementation is not scalable :(

Answer (score 3):

Pascal's number performance in ms

```
c,r     Scala   Erlang
10,20   21      22
11,22   6       72
12,24   16      272
13,26   71      1034
14,28   299     3982
15,30   802     16124
16,32   3885    60420
```